# How to know number of cores utilized by a stage in spark

Tags: apache-spark

How to know number of cores utilized by a stage in spark. Shall we treat number of tasks in a stage is equal to number of cores. Since, each task runs on a separate core.

Comment: Spark UI page..

Answer (score 1):

Spark UI is the easiest possible way.Navigate to "Environment" tab in Spark UI.
From YARN, click on the application Id & then on the Tracking URL. It directs to the Spark UI page